# Cloud Storage - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage

This question has been asked before, but in my case, things are a little different.

See, I already ran the following command:

```
 gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://(repo)
```

But the Javascript is trying to get data from an image in the bucket, and the CORS policy is blocking me. Obviously the command works for the bucket itself, not files in the bucket.

I used the following command:

```
gsutil cors get gs:/(bucket)
```

And I get: [{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "POST"], "origin": ["https://(domain).com"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]}]

The code calling the bucket is actually calling the image URL:

```
Articles.Croppie.bind({
            url: image.attr('src').replace('medium/', 'large/'),
            points: points,
            zoom: 0,
            orientation: 1
        }).then(function() {
            Articles.Croppie.setZoom(0);
        });
```

And it is the script that CORS policy is blocking.

```
Access to image at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/(bucket)/(image)' from origin 'https://www.(domain).com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: Use the CLI tool `curl` to debug CORS. https://reqbin.com/req/c-taimahsa/curl-cors-request Your post does not show the contents of `cors-json-file.json` nor the web browser HTTP request.

Comment: [
    {
      "origin": ["https://(domain).com"],
      "responseHeader": "Content-Type",
      "method": ["GET", "POST"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]

Comment: Have you tried Troubleshooting CORS requests? See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-cors#troubleshooting).

Comment: I'll try that. I am thinking that the bucket is set to Subject to object ACLs. Maybe that's the issue

Comment: It is working now. The CORS configuration ended up working after all.